# How to put a Spinner beside a RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, spinner, radio-group

I have this layout:

(since my reputation is not yet 10 I sincerely ask you to view this image link)
http://tinypic.com/r/2q9f80z/5

I want to put a Spinner beside the last RadioButton as you can see in the picture.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Linearlayout containing the Search/Find Customer -->


    <!-- TextView for Search/Find Customer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search/Find Customer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/roundable_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/hint_search" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Search" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search/Find Customer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdAllCustomers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="All Customers" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Today" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Owner\&apos;s Name" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Trade Name" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Itinerary" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/spinner_itinerary"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Man, you should not use a spinner beside a radio button, this isnt a good design practice, instead you should put your spinner under the radio button, and if the user select the radiobutton you turn your spinner visible.

Comment: Is that a protocol in Android? My project is to imitate a .Net program from Windows Phone(iPAQ), and its appearance is that the spinner is beside the radio button.

Comment: Its not a protocol, its just a better practice design. The way you are thinking looks like kind desorganized, you know?

Comment: I said it is my project's requirement and not the way I think. Also you misspelled the word "disorganized". Anyway thanks for the enlightenment, I will say that to my team lead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Witalo. Imitating of non-Android mobile OSes' (iOS, Windows Phone etc.) designs is highly not recommended on the Android Design Guide. However, if your client/customer requires it, you have the following options which I can think of,

- Sub-class `RadioButton` that draws a `Spinner` instead
- Or, make use of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, I appreciate it. I may do both the one with a spinner beside the radiobutton and the spinner below the radiobutton so I can present it to my team lead. I also find it silly to exactly imitate the looks of a non-android program since their behavior is very different.